# Why can std::find_if potentially fail with std::bad_alloc exception?

Tags: c++, stl

As I stated in the title, I just can't understand why does this function throw `std::bad_alloc`. If we take a look at the [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) all of the three possible implementations are just as someone would assume and it looks like there is no special need dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: It's right in the link you posted: `If the algorithm fails to allocate memory, std::bad_alloc is thrown`

Comment: I think the question is more along the lines of:  why would the algorithm ever need to try to allocate memory in the first place?

Comment: Maybe, there is room left for efficient algorithms which need some kind of look-up tables or other supplementary data. [Boyer–Moore string-search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm): _Preprocessing ... requires two tables_

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I would say yes, the actual question comes down to that one.

Comment: @AviBerger Let me get this right, overloads without execution policy should be safe (noexcept) ?

Comment: I'd say no, since they aren't declared `noexcept`.

Comment: @AviBerger The default is that a standard library function without `noexcept` specification is allowed to throw implementation-defined exceptions (see https://eel.is/c++draft/res.on.exception.handling#4) and `find_if` doesn't have any "_Throws:_" clause constraining that (https://eel.is/c++draft/alg.find).

Comment: @Godra Why exactly is it important whether this algorithm can throw `std::bad_alloc`? Most standard library functions could potentially throw, especially `std::bad_alloc`. If you want to handle `std::bad_alloc` gracefully you'll have to write almost all of your code with the assumption that anything not `noexcept` may throw.

Comment: @user17732522 If you want to handle `std::bad_alloc` gracefully, you have to jump through hoops to recover from the fact that you can't allocate anything!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The 3 possible implementations shown in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) are for the 3 overloads that do not take an execution policy. It is specifically the overloads that do take an execution policy that are specifically listed as possibly throwing std::bad_alloc.

Execution policy involves the possibility of parallelizing or vectorizing the operation. That would require extra memory to pull off rather than just relying on the scalar variables in the non parallelized/vectorized version.

Edit: That said, as @user17732522 said in comments:

> The default is that a standard library function without noexcept
> specification is allowed to throw implementation-defined exceptions
> ([see eel.is/c++draft/res.on.exception.handling#4](https://eel.is/c++draft/res.on.exception.handling#4)) and find_if doesn't
> have any "Throws:" clause constraining that
> ([eel.is/c++draft/alg.find](https://eel.is/c++draft/alg.find)).

So an implementation is allowed to provide a std::find that does throw for any of the overloads.

Answer (score 13):

It's because of the execution policy in the template.

"the C++ standard permits parallel algorithms to allocate memory, and throw std::bad_alloc when they can’t acquire memory"

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/using-c17-parallel-algorithms-for-better-performance/